# filter rows if any of the two columns have the specified value

Tags: r, select

I have a data frame with 7 columns say a1, a2,...., a7. a1 and a2 have numeric values while the rest have strings (athlete names in this case). I want to select rows that "John" and "Peter" appear together in any two of the columns (a3 to a7). In the example below, I want to select only row 2 and 4.

Example

[image] .

I've searched all over the internet, but can't find any direction. Does anyone have any idea? Is it doable? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  a1 = c(14,23,24,6,4),
  a2 = c(5,67,4,57,54),
  a3 = c("Paul", "John", "Mike", "Peter", "John"),
  a4 = c("John", "Phil", "Peter", "John", "Luke"),
  a5 = c("Dave", "Peter", "Nick", "Paul", "Phil"),
  a6 = c("Adrian", "Keim", "Rick", "Luke", "Mike"),
  a7 = c("Rick", "Luke", "Adrian", "Rick", "Dave")
)

df %>%
  filter_all(
    any_vars(. == "Peter")
  ) %>%
  filter_all(
    any_vars(. == "John")
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, you can do

```
cols <- 3:7
df[rowSums(df[cols] == 'John') > 0 & rowSums(df[cols] == 'Peter') > 0, ]
```

OR with `apply`

```
subset(df, apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) all(c('John', 'Peter') %in% x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R solution by defining your custom function `f` as filter, i.e.,

```
f <- Vectorize(function(pat) grepl(pat,do.call(paste,df)))
dfout <- subset(df,do.call(`&`,data.frame(f(c("\\bJohn\\b","\\bPeter\\b")))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  a1 a2    a3   a4    a5   a6   a7
2 23 67  John Phil Peter Keim Luke
4  6 57 Peter John  Paul Luke Rick
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(a1 = c(14, 23, 24, 6, 4), a2 = c(5, 67, 4, 57, 
54), a3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("John", 
"Mike", "Paul", "Peter"), class = "factor"), a4 = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("John", "Luke", "Peter", "Phil"), class = "factor"), 
    a5 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Dave", 
    "Nick", "Paul", "Peter", "Phil"), class = "factor"), a6 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Adrian", "Keim", "Luke", "Mike", 
    "Rick"), class = "factor"), a7 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L), .Label = c("Adrian", "Dave", "Luke", "Rick"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```